# How can I calculate time different from file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

this is my first post so please bear with me, I want to calculate the time different from ssh log file which have format like this

```
Jan 10 hr:min:sec Failed password for invalid user root from "ip" port xxx ssh2
Jan 10 hr:min:sec sshd[]: User root from "ip" not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
```

The script will alert when user fail to login x times within 10 minutes, any can please teach me how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: What do you want to extract from text above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specification is a little ambiguous - presumably there are going to be more than two lines in your log file - do you want the time difference between successive lines?  Do you want a line parsed searching for a keyword (such as "failed login") and then the time difference to a different line similarly parsed?

Since I can't tell from what you've provided, I'm simply going to presume that there are two lines in a file which have a date at the start of each line and you want the time difference between those dates.  You can then manipulate to do what you want.  Alternatively, add to your question and define exactly what a "failed login" is.

There are many ways to skin this cat but I prefer the `strptime` function from [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-Format-Strptime-1.67/lib/DateTime/Format/Strptime.pm) which is described as;

*This module implements most of strptime(3), the POSIX function that is the reverse of strftime(3), for DateTime. While strftime takes a DateTime and a pattern and returns a string, strptime takes a string and a pattern and returns the DateTime object associated.*

This will do as I've described above;

```
use v5.12;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $logfile = "ssh.log";
open(my $fh, '<', $logfile) or die "$logfile: $!";

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%h %d %T ',
    time_zone => 'local',
    on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $dt1 = $strp->parse_datetime(scalar <$fh>);
my $dt2 = $strp->parse_datetime(scalar <$fh>);

my $duration = $dt2->subtract_datetime_absolute($dt1);
say "Number of seconds difference is: ", $duration->seconds ;
#
# Input
# Jan 10 14:03:18 Failed password for invalid user root from "ip" port xxx ssh2
# Jan 10 14:03:22 sshd[]: User root from "ip" not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
#
# Outputs:
# Number of seconds difference is: 4
```

A more comprehensive answer (making even more assumptions) is below:

```
use v5.12;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use DateTime::Duration;

my $logfile = "ssh.log";
my $maximum_failures_allowed = 3 ;
my $minimum_time_frame = 10 * 60;  # in seconds

my $limit = $maximum_failures_allowed - 1 ;

# The following is a list of rules indicating a
# failed login for the username captured in $1
my @rules = (
      qr/Failed password for user (\S+) / ,
      qr/User (\S+) from [\d\.]+ not allowed/
   );

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%h %d %T ',
    time_zone => 'local',
    on_error  => 'croak',
);

my %usernames ;

open(my $fh, '<', $logfile) or die "$logfile: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    for my $rx (@rules) {
        if ( /$rx/ )  {
            # rule matched -> login fail for $1.  Save log line.
            my $user = $1 ;
            push  @{ $usernames{$user} }  ,  $_ ;

            # No point checking other rules...
            last ;
        }
    }
}
close $fh ;

for my $user (keys %usernames) {
    my @failed_logins = @{ $usernames{$user} };

    # prime the loop; we know there is at least one failed login
    my $this_line  = shift @failed_logins ;

    while ( @failed_logins > $limit )  {
        my $other_line = $failed_logins[ $limit ] ;
        my $this_time  = $strp->parse_datetime($this_line) ;
        my $other_time = $strp->parse_datetime($other_line) ;

        #  this produces a DateTime::Duration object with the difference in seconds
        my $time_frame = $other_time->subtract_datetime_absolute( $this_time );

        if ($time_frame->seconds < $minimum_time_frame) {
            say   "User $user had login failures at the following times:" ;
            print "  $_" for $this_line, @failed_logins[ 0 .. $limit ] ;

            # (s)he may have more failures but let's not labour the point
            last ;
        }

        # Here if user had too many failures but within a reasonable time frame
        # Continue to move through the array of failures checking time frames
        $this_line  = shift @failed_logins ;
    }
}
exit 0;
```

Ran on this data;

```
Jan 10 14:03:18 sshd[15798]: Failed password for user root from "ip" port xxx ssh2
Jan 10 14:03:22 sshd[15798]: User root from 188.124.3.41 not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups
Jan 10 20:31:12 sshd[15798]: Connection from 188.124.3.41 port 32889
Jan 10 20:31:14 sshd[15798]: Failed password for user root from 188.124.3.41 port 32889 ssh2
Jan 10 20:31:14 sshd[29323]: Received disconnect from 188.124.3.41: 11: Bye Bye
Jan 10 22:04:56 sshd[25438]: Connection from 200.54.84.233 port 45196
Jan 10 22:04:58 sshd[25438]: Failed password for user root from 200.54.84.233 port 45196 ssh2
Jan 10 22:04:58 sshd[30487]: Received disconnect from 200.54.84.233: 11: Bye Bye
Jan 10 22:04:59 sshd[21358]: Connection from 200.54.84.233 port 45528
Jan 10 22:05:01 sshd[21358]: Failed password for user root from 200.54.84.233 port 45528 ssh2
Jan 10 22:05:02 sshd[2624]: Received disconnect from 200.54.84.233: 11: Bye Bye
Jan 10 22:05:29 sshd[21358]: Connection from 200.54.84.233 port 45528
Jan 10 22:05:30 sshd[21358]: Failed password for user root from 200.54.84.233 port 45528 ssh2
Jan 10 22:05:33 sshd[2624]: Received disconnect from 200.54.84.233: 11: Bye Bye
Jan 10 22:06:49 sshd[21358]: Connection from 200.54.84.233 port 45528
Jan 10 22:06:51 sshd[21358]: Failed password for user root from 200.54.84.233 port 45528 ssh2
Jan 10 22:06:51 sshd[2624]: Received disconnect from 200.54.84.233: 11: Bye Bye
```

... it produces this output;

```
User root had login failures at the following times:
  Jan 10 22:04:58 sshd[25438]: Failed password for user root from 200.54.84.233 port 45196 ssh2
  Jan 10 22:05:01 sshd[21358]: Failed password for user root from 200.54.84.233 port 45528 ssh2
  Jan 10 22:05:30 sshd[21358]: Failed password for user root from 200.54.84.233 port 45528 ssh2
  Jan 10 22:06:51 sshd[21358]: Failed password for user root from 200.54.84.233 port 45528 ssh2
```

Note that the timezone and/or offset is not present in the logfile data - so, there is no way for this script to work correctly on the day you enter or leave "Daylight Savings."

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marty!!. Sorry if my question is a bit confuse.
Yes, there are more than one lines in the file and it might have more that one ip that try to login in the period of time. Assume that "failed login" mean that user fail to verify themselves which record as one log. So, I need to know if any of ip in the log file that fail to verify themselves more that 10 times in 10 minutes. So, how can I know if there are two "ip" try to login in the same time, do I need to save the list of ip in the file?